# directory_seperator vs path_seperator when and how to use

Tags: php

I was wondering when would one use php's `PATH_SEPERATOR` in code. I know it prints out a colon.

Why are there two constants, `DIRECTORY_SEPERATOR` and `PATH_SEPERATOR`, which have names that are synonymous?

I know that `PATH_SEPERATOR` prints out a slash.

When I think of either a path separator or a directory separator the thing that comes to mind is `/`.

Example of `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` use:

```
include 'files' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'images' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'image.jpg';
```

PHP's [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php) doesn't really say much.

Comment: Just a note here on top of the other answers... DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR is not really needed when creating paths. You only need to use it when dealing with paths that might be returned by the various filesystem functions, as different OSs can return different results. Using a / for building the path in your example above is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although one might think they have synonymous names their job is actually quite different.

You use `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` when you build a path to a folder or file.

You use `PATH_SEPARATOR` when you're building the string for a collection of path and the `PATH_SEPARATOR` is used to separate individual paths in that collection.

Example:

```
$location1 = "include_folder".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."subfolder1";
$location2 = "include_folder".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."subfolder2";
$path_collection = $location1.PATH_SEPARATOR.$location2;
```

Comment: An example outside of PHP is path lookup locations, for instance the PATH environmental variable on windows uses it to list locations to find command executables.

Answer (score 0):

`DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` is used to separate elements of a single path. `PATH_SEPARATOR` is used to separate multiple paths as a single value, e.g. in [`include_path`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path).

Answer (score 0):

A `DIRECTORY_SEPERATOR` separates directories (/ or \) e.g.

```
/home/your_user_name
```

A `PATH_SEPERATOR` separates paths (: or ;) e.g.

```
/home/your_user_name:/var/www/web0
```

Note that you don't have to use `DIRECTORY_SEPERATOR` as long as you stick to `/`. Windows and linux both understand this.

Answer (score 0):

This is not just php. In general, directory separators and path separators are two different things.

A directory separator is withing **one** directory. For example, on unix, `a/b/c` has a directory separator or `'/'`. On windows, it would (probably :-) be `a\b\c` with a separator of `'\\'` (extra backslash for escape :-).

A path separator delineates multiple directories ... for example, consider the following search path:

```
/bin:/usr/bin:/home/me/bin
```

Within this search path containing 3 directories. Each of the 3 dirs uses '/' as its DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, but the search path as a whole uses a PATH_SEPARATOR of ':' to delimit the constituent directories.

It means, first look in /bin, then if not there look in /usr/bin, then if not there look in /home/me/bin.

Hope this helps.